# How to disable wordpress confirmation email for new users

Tags: php, email, user-registration

I need to disable Wordpress new user registration email confirmation link and auto generated password for new users.

Users should be register with a password of their choice without email confirmation link

Comment: [Disable New User Notification Emails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-new-user-notifications/) plugin can helps you.

Answer (score 4):

I noticed the current answers are plugin based only.

You can use `wpmu_signup_user_notification` to achieve this without installing a plugin.

Add to your `functions.php` - this will disable user signup notifcations completely.

```
add_filter( 'wpmu_signup_user_notification', '__return_false' );
```

You can read more `wpmu_signup_user_notification` here:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wpmu_signup_user_notification/

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I'm on a multisite with a parent/child theme (and 2 subsites). I've tried added that line to both the parent, and the child and both, - and still no luck. I'm unable to add a user to a subsite, without the user having to confirm it first.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use a plugin for that. Have a look at:

- [Secure Invites](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-secure-invites/) - An advanced plugin but got some issues at my installations.
- [Invite Friends to Register](https://wordpress.org/plugins/invite-friends-to-register/) - Less settings but easy to use at the front-end.

They both work like this:

1. Allow registration in general settings.
2. Invite user by entering (a name and) email.
3. The user receives an email and will be pointed to the registration form.
4. The user will fill in the form (username and email).
5. After the user submitted the form, the user is created. You (admin mail) will receive a notification and the user will receive a mail with their username, a generated password and login URL.

Comment: I think this is not solition for my question. it's about invite visitors and user.

Comment: @Tabeno So far it looks like you want to allow visitors to invite their selves to the registration form? But that doesn't make any sense, why don't just point them to the registration form? Please explain the process of inviting. Users can't be invited, they already are in the system.

Answer (score 0):

This plugin is said to allow users to choose their passwords when registering:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-my-login/