# It is possible that to get data in wp_login.php to your own php file in wordpress?

Tags: wp-login-form

Hi everyone I'm new in wordpress development. I have difficulty cause my Registration page is no password input but there's automatic password given every register. So I would like to get the password of what I register. I'll give you the image. [image: wp-login.php screenshot]

And I would like to get the value of username to put in my own php file. How to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should include your php file in `functions.php` in WordPress theme folder. 
In functions.php : `require( 'your_php_file' );`
And write :

```
<?php
    add_action( 'init', 'fetch_login_form');
    function fetch_login_form() {
        $user_email = $_POST['user_email'];
        // write condition based on Username or User email.
    }
```

Password is autogenerated while we receive an email so you can stop send email and allow user to register directly. Follow this link : [How to disable wordpress confirmation email for new users](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/177007/how-to-disable-wordpress-confirmation-email-for-new-users)